# Simple Schema for Meteor - how to use JS to check for the presence of a value in a hash inside the Schema?

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is my form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="domainSelected" id="domainCheckbox" value="True">Would you like a domain URL?

<div class="col-md-12">
  {{> afQuickField name="domainURL" }}
</div>
```

I've got this in my schema:

```
  domainSelected: {
    type: String,
    label: "Domain Selected?",
    optional: true
  },
  domainURL: {
    type: String,
    label: "Domain Name",
    optional: // I want this to be false IF domainSelected exists. True IF domainSelected does not exist.
  },
```

Can I get some help here? Would it be something like:

```
  domainSelected: {
    type: String,
    label: "Domain Selected?",
    optional: true
  },
  domainURL: {
    type: String,
    label: "Domain Name",
    optional: function() {
      if ( $('#domainCheckbox').prop('checked') ) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      };
    }
  },
```

When I do this my meteor doesn't load and I get a console error:

```
Error: Invalid definition for domainURL field.
```

**EDIT**

To clarify:

On my frontend I have a checkbox (#domainCheckbox) and a form field where a user can input a domain name as a string.

When the checkbox is selected, the form field is required in the schema and Simple-Schema's form validations will fail if the form field is left blank.

When the checkbox is not selected, the form field is not required in the schema and Simple-Schema will no longer check for the presence of something in that field.

**EDIT**
Erm, actually the code works.... sometimes... other times meteor just crashes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: [simpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#validate-one-key-against-another)

```
  domainSelected: {
    type: String,
    label: "Domain Selected?",
    optional: true
  },
  domainURL: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Domain Name",
    autoValue: function() {
      if ( this.field('domainSelected').value == '' ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      };
    }
  },
```

You can access a field from another field. Checking again '' isnt maybe the best way but I think its the way to go.

**Edit:**

Ok, some ideas how I would do it. I would not insert the jQuery statement into the schema. The schema runs on client and server it will fail always on serverside.

Your domainSelected field is in the HTML-View a checkbox. A checkbox just takes true or false as argument. So the domainSelectedfield should be a Boolean. Thus a checkbox just has two states, true OR false it isnt an optional parameter. Because if the checkbox is not selected it is false.

```
  domainSelected: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Domain Selected?"
  }
```

If domainSelected is true than domainUrl is required. If domainSelected is false than domainUrl should be empty.

```
 domainURL: {
    type: String,
    label: "Domain Name",
    autoValue: function() {
      if ( this.field('domainSelected').value === true && this.value !== "") {
        return this.value;
      } else if(this.field('domainSelected').value === false) {
        return ""; 
      }else
      {
        this.unset();
      };
    }
  }
```

I didnt tested it but it should fit your solution.

Comment: `domainURL` is supposed to be an actual URL, so it should be `type: String` I want the function the set `optional` to either `true` or `false` for the `domainURL` key, depending on if `domain` was checked or not.

Comment: I dont get it. Could you explain better which field is optional and which should return true/false depending on which field? If the checkbox is a checkbox inside your html you should use hooks.

Comment: Ok, my code in the screenshot only works *some* of the time. I think this is a meteor load order issue. Sometimes the schema code is run after jQuery is loaded, and sometimes the schema code tries to run before jQuery is loaded. I sometimes get the meteor console error and sometimes I don't.

Comment: I made a an edit. Maybe this could fit a bit better to your solution.